# gradlew.bat (and gradlew) SSLHandShakeException

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm new to Gradle and was going through this Spring Tutorial found here:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

I get to the part where it tells me to add this task:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
     gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

I run gradle wrapper which creates the gradlew and gradlew.bat files.

Trying to run both of this I get this exception:

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.val
idator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.cert
path.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to req
uested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.
java:1341)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.jav
a:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.
java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339
)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323
)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:
563)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1300)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Http
sURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:56)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:42)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:57)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find vali
d certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.jav
a:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.j
ava:326)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerIm
pl.java:231)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustMan
agerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.
java:1323)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
 find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCert
PathBuilder.java:196)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
        ... 25 more
```

I try to hit the webserver at https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip and I'm not getting any sort of error. I'm I missing some sort of config? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I experienced the same problem, however my symptoms were that my Ubuntu machine couldn't resolve any SSL hosts unless I specifically added them to Java's certificate authority (cacert) file.

I stumbled upon this Debian bug, and found a fairly straight-forward resolution: remove `ca-certificates-java` and install it again:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

I did a `./gradlew clean` for good measure, and everything sprung to life again.

Comment: This also solves a similar issue I encountered when using IntelliJ IDEA to work on gradle projects.

Comment: How can I do the same on a windows machine? I am unable to find a similar solution for windows.

Answer (score 43):

if you could not fix anyway. and if you are inside firewall.
then.
you may can not download https.

should fix that Edit gradle-wrapper.properties file.

```
vi [project]/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-bin.zip 
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-bin.zip
```

change from https to http...

http://blog.cjred.net/gradlew-bat-and-gradlew-sslhandshakeexception/

After I modified, it says: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip

Answer (score 4):

#### Steps:

1. Run `gradlew -Djavax.net.debug=all tasks`
2. Go through the debug logs, and see if you find anything out of the ordinary.

In my case, seeing something like `Zscaler` did the trick, as i know i have `Zscaler` on(which by the way **rewrites the TLS traffic** blablabla), and it was trying to find the *valid certification path to requested target*, which obviously it couldn't find.

#### 2 Options:

1. Exit `Zscaler`
2. If exiting `Zscaler` is not an option, go to your browser, **export** `Zscaler Root Certificate`

   ```
    If you are using Brave browser, here are the steps:
    Settings > Privacy and security > Manage device certificates > Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Find Zscaler Root CA > Export
   ```

   and import it in the JVM truststore `gradle` is using, something like:

   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias Zscaler -file "Zscaler Root CA.cer" -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%"\jre\lib\security\cacerts

**IMPORTANT**: Do a `gradlew clean` before retrying any command.

Comment: 3 months later, i had the same issue, and obviously i don't remember how to fix it, so i googled. Guess what!? I stumble upon my own answer!!! Long live SO!!! Too bad i can't vote for myself ;-)

Comment: turning off Zscaler then running gradlew clean worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that the certificates for the gradle site were messed up. Doing a `gradlew clean` should fix this. See this thread on the Gradle forum: http://discuss.gradle.org/t/urgent-ssl-apache-configuration-for-services-gradle-org-is-bad/8808/4

Comment: Thank you very much, that indeed appears to have been the problem, it is working now.

Comment: How do I find gradlew command? I'm using Eclipse and unable to create a gradle project, so there is no gradlew on my system?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was on a company network and behind a proxy, which as I understand it rewrites the SSL certificates, making the Java installation not trust any of them.

To solve it I had to create a gradle.properties file in my home directory under .gradle (`~/.gradle/gradle.properties`) and add the following line:

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-DsystemProp.https.proxyHost=<myProxyHost> -DsystemProp.https.proxyPort=<myProxyPort> -DsystemProp.https.proxyUser=<myProxyUsername> -DsystemProp.https.proxyPassword=<myProxyPassword>`

That solution was based on this SO answer: [Gradle use certificate authentication for repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202894/gradle-use-certificate-authentication-for-repository)

Comment: This helped me out, as my company uses Netskope to re-write SSL certs on the fly. In my case, simply setting org.gradle.jvmargs=-DsystemProp.https.proxyHost=<company goskope host> solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by an obsolete (7 years old) version of Java. Even `gradlew clean` did fail. After a Java update it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is because, Gradle tries to find the installed package in your local machine.
If you have the installed location:

> D:\apps\gradle-3.3

Follow these steps in eclipse:

1. New Project
2. Gradle Project
3. Enter project Name
4. Local Installation Directory
5. Click Finish.

You are good to go.

Answer (score -3):

Create this profile in user home:

`$ vi ~/.yarnrc`

`# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.`

`# yarn lockfile v1`

`strict-ssl false`