# Gradle build failed behind proxy

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to build [Spring music app](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music) using Gradle. This is the command I'm trying to use:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

It fails as follows:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
>
>   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.1.RELEASE.
>   >     Required by:
>   >       project :
>   >     Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.1.RELEASE.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.1.RELEASE.pom'.
>   >     Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.1.RELEASE.pom'.
>   >     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   >     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   >     find valid certification path to requested target

I had a look on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202894/gradle-use-certificate-authentication-for-repository) and did the following:

1- Created ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and put the following inside:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="/Users/myusername/my_private_company_ca_bundle" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=KeychainStore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

2- Also I added my CA bundle (Root CA and intermediate CA in one file)

```
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file ./certificates/my_private_company_ca_bundle -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Also, I made sure I'm putting my proxy settings in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<corporate_proxy>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<corporate_proxy>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

Here is my Java version:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

What could be missing in my settings?

Comment: (as you know,) the "PKIX error" is due to missing certificates in you java cacerts file. You already tried importing them- but either you imported the wrong certificates; or the Jvm in use to run Gradle is not the same where you imported the certs...

Comment: you can double-check what jvm you are using; add to you gradle build file: `println(org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current());
println(String.class.getResource('/java/lang/Object.class'));`